# How to get SIM ip address for ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I need to know the source IP for my iPad using my SIM network. Is there any way to get source IP address for SIM network

Answer (score 0):

Go to a website like e.g. http://www.whatsmyip.org and there you can see your public IP address.